# Is it possible to do ruby-debug on a remote server?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, debugging

I'm trying to debug a remote server.

How would I perform ruby-debug and access the console through breakpoints?

Is that possible to do and click through the site to activate those breakpoints?

Comment: RubyMine does this well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ruby-debug has had out-of-process debugging for a long while. In fact the code mentioned in that Noufal Ibrahim cites, is using the same underlying common code.

However I've just added some documentation describing how it works in the reference manual.

See http://bashdb.sourceforge.net/ruby-debug.html#Remote-Debugging and http://bashdb.sourceforge.net/ruby-debug.html#Out_002dof_002dprocess-execution-options

Comment: The links are broken - project seems to have migrated to github. Generally, it is a good idea to not just add links as the main content of an answer...

Answer (score 0):

If you can ssh to the server, you're probably better of running your debugger locally over there.

Otherwise, you might want to take a look at http://blogs.oracle.com/martink/entry/remote_debugging_debug_whatever_ruby.

Comment: I can ssh in. But running it locally, how would that work since I have no browser to access it. Do you have an example?

Comment: I've not used `ruby` at all. It this a web application you're dealing with? Why the whole business of the browser at all?

Comment: @Nourfal, Ah yes. it is a web application. And I'm trying to debug an error when I click on a link. But I suppose the same thing can be handled remotely by setting breakpoints and telling it to explitictly run a specific point of the script. I just can't figure out where/how to do that.

Comment: Can't you startup the debugger on your remote server, connect to the backend process and then use your regular browser to trigger the action that causes the breakpoint to be hit? Your browser doesn't have to be on the remote machine.

Comment: No I don't believe that is possible. At least not to my knowlege.

Comment: Because if I ran the server remotely, it would assigned to a specific port `:3000`, and I can't access a port through my browser to my knowlege.

Comment: http://yoursite.com:3000 would be the URL. Assuming it's publicly accessible. Otherwise, you can always use curl/wget from your dev machine directly.

Comment: The blogs.oracle.com link is broken. Generally, it is a good idea to not just add links as the main content of an answer...